# Set the div width as per content

Tags: css, html, width

I need to set the div width as browser default width. This div is containing 'ul' and 'li' elements. I need to increase the div width When 'li' content increases and aslo when browser is minimized this li elements should not go down (happening now) instead browser should provide horizantal bar. Any help?

Div structure is

```
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid red; line-height:16px;width:100%">
    <ul style="position:relative;background:green;height:30px; width:100%;list-style:none; margin:0;">
        <li style="position:relative; display:inline-block; padding-left:20px; float:left; background:red" >Welcome</li>
        <li style="position:relative; display:inline-block; padding-left:20px; float:left; background:red" >Welcome</li>
        <li style="position:relative; display:inline-block; padding-left:20px; float:left; background:red" >Welcome</li>
        <li style="position:relative; display:inline-block; padding-left:20px; float:left; background:red" >Welcome</li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi used **display properties** as like this

```
ul li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/cL9FB/

Answer (score 1):

Rohit was close, but the `display: inline-block` needs to be applied to the `div`, not to the `li`.  Also, `width: 100%` on your `div` and `ul` will actually do the opposite of what you want; take it off.

Also, you wanted no word-wrapping - I'm not sure whether that's possible to achieve with floats, but it is possible with `display: inline-block`, which does almost the same thing.  That means removing `float: left`, because that will override any display declaration.  After that, just add `white-space: nowrap` to the `div` or `ul` to prevent word-wrapping.

Using `display: inline-block` does create the annoying quirk that any whitespace between the `li`s will create a visible gap - so you can't put any whitespace between the `li`s, not even newlines.  I like to deal with this by moving the ending `>` sign to just before the starting `<` sign of the next tag - this solves the problem, since only whitespace between `>` and `<` counts.

Updated code:

```
<div style="position:relative; border:1px solid red; line-height:16px; display:inline-block">
    <ul style="position:relative; background:green; height:30px; list-style:none; margin:0; white-space: nowrap"
        ><li style="position:relative; padding-left:20px; display:inline-block; background:red" >Welcome</li
        ><li style="position:relative; padding-left:20px; display:inline-block; background:red" >Welcome</li
        ><li style="position:relative; padding-left:20px; display:inline-block; background:red" >Welcome</li
        ><li style="position:relative; padding-left:20px; display:inline-block; background:red" >Welcome</li
    ></ul>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gncGX/2/

Comment: The result with the given code is not as per my requirement. li element should float left. when browser is minimized li elements shouldnt go down.

Comment: Whoops - apparently my code trimming was overzealous.  I've edited my answer to only make the changes that are really necessary - hopefully it does meet your requirements now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, but I'll try my best. I think you need to put div width in percentage

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And all your other element also should have width in percentages

Answer (score 0):

Set width value of all elements (particularly `<li>`) in percentage, not in pixels;
for ex, if you have 5 li, give them width:20%. their parent;s width should be 100%

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you want a fluid layout that will keep its basic design, shape and content layout no matter what the resolution, browser size or device. To be honest a fluid layout is best for this and there are many open source solutions.

Have a look at this http://cssgrid.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width:auto;
}
```

job done.

Comment: can you explain a bit more extensively your answer? tnx